# Extremism: what’s the cultural history of this word?

Tags: etymology, historical-change, sociolinguistics

“Extremism” sounds like an ideology, by analogy with Marxism for example. Or it could be akin to a behavioural state like mutism or autism. With respect to these different directions, I’m wondering what the word’s political and cultural history is.

Lexico defines **extremism** as

> The holding of [extreme political or religious views](https://www.lexico.com/definition/extremism); fanaticism.
> *‘Otherwise their anger and frustration can lead to religious extremism’*

Comment: I take offense at calling _autism_ a 
"defect"...and we don't do translations into other languages here.

Comment: "-ism" was obviously borrowed from *transcendentalism*.  Of course, that borrowed from *rationalism*.  Which of course borrowed from *romanticism*.

Comment: I concur with Cascabel. While I hesitate at the 100-rep penalty, you **must** edit this question.

Comment: That said, it's difficult to say how "the word's political and cultural history" is on-topic anyway.

Comment: What the OP is probably seeking is an explanation of why it is that we can use the word *extreme* for extreme goodness, extreme kindness, extreme helpfulness, etc., but we never use the word *extrem**ism*** for the pursuit of anything like that, even though it is obviously derived from *extreme*. How did the word end up being limited to only certain kinds of extremes?

Comment: @Chris, can you be more explicit about what you want in an answer? As is it is a bit underspecified. It's unlikely to attract answers about the use of 'extremism' in the NYT to describe the difference between [the IRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_Republican_Army) and the [PLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestine_Liberation_Organization) and how that came from earlier use of [IRGUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irgun). You should specify the particular cultural and historical things you care about with examples. But you may want to ask [history.SE] about this.

Comment: [-ism is not just about religion or government](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ity): "Roughly, the word in -ity usually means the quality of being what the adjective describes, or concretely an instance of the quality, or collectively all the instances; & the word in -ism means the disposition, or collectively all those who feel it. [Fowler]". Sure, there's 'Catholicism' and 'communism' but there's also 'witticism' and 'nepotism'.

Comment: I really wonder if *extra* + *mismo* ("same") would have any meaning in Spanish or vulgar Latin to the effect of implying "unequal", "enemy", maybe sheer coincidence to be homophone with *extreme* which doesn't even have the necessary superlative morphemes to match the superlative semantics. Difficult to tell really as long as the etymology of *mismo*, VLat. \*metipse, \*metipsimus is not entirely clear. cp. *to match* "equal" (from Germanic) and *no match, boxing match* (apparently a loan) for similar semantics. A notion of "opposition" might explain the chief negative connotation in question

Comment: Interesting thought vectory.  The psychology of etymology comes in here.  The etymological facts are one thing,  but the

Answer (score 3):

The word is a simple construct derived from the adjective *extreme* and seems unlikely to have a strong cultural development as opposed to filling a linguistic niche for a suitable related noun. According to Google ngram its use has increased steadily since the early 1900s.

> Extremism = "the fact of someone having beliefs that most people think are unreasonable and unacceptable"
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/extremism)

This meaning accords with other dictionaries and with common usage. The beliefs, which may be of any form (for examples: leftist/rightist, religious/atheistic, nationalist/globalist, communist/capitalist), are not innate but are **chosen** by the believers.

Because extremism is related to behaviour that is by definition outside that condoned by most people it is not akin to Marxism, which has a set of particular beliefs open to as many people as **choose** to embrace it.

Nor is it reasonably likened to mutism or autism, both of which are human conditions characteristic of some people but not in any sense **chosen** by them.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make my position clear and for the avoidance of doubt.

Comment: Merrimack Webster tells me that *defective* may be offensive. It does not say so for *defect*. Some may consider your use of *crap* equally offensive; it is certainly vulgar. We are in the land of opinion.

Comment: I've lost the plot re defect.  I am more interested in usage than in essentialist definitions. It's sad but possibly true that many 'isms' are in usage terms liable to communicate pathology or defect. Not my view of autism but it is used by an

Comment: @jsw29 Yes I merely intended it in the sense "*An innate quality or ability is one that you were born with, not one you have learned*" (Cambridge dictionary). My implication is that no belief is innate (beliefs are instead learned or chosen), whereas other attributes and conditions such as those mentioned, stemming from ontogenesis and manifested after birth, cannot be learned or chosen.

Answer (score 0):

OED:
Extremism:

> Etymology: < extreme adj., adv., and n. + -ism suffix.
>
> **Tendency to be extreme; disposition to go to extremes.**
>
> 1865   Daily Telelegraph. 29 Dec. 2/1   *These days of extravagance and extremeism.*
>
> 1887   The American XIII. 276   *It is..this extremism which makes any effective control of the traffic in liquors so nearly hopeless.*

The 1865 quote may be a reference to the suppression of the [Morant Bay rebellion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morant_Bay_rebellion) by [Edward John Eyre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_John_Eyre#Colonial_Governor_in_Jamaica) and the events that followed.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of wording to describe good extremes is, likely, because there can not be any good extremes.  The extremism, itself.

A person can be extremely normal, healthy, etc, in terms of mental acuity, and, physical strength, but, these traits, themselves, aren't extremes.  Even the loftiest theories and other such works require a balanced view of things.  Even great physical strength requires efficient muscles.

Being extremely generous, in the sense of handing out your life's savings, say, to strangers on a street corner, may be considered crazy behavior.  Similarly, an extreme lottery win of tens of millions of dollars often leads to the complete demise of winners.  Relatively extreme acts of charity pale in comparison to incremental sustained good in the community by keeping the overall wealth there.  Some cures may be worse than others, as require more hardship by the patient, but, cures, themselves, aren't extreme.  Trace amounts of poisons, in balanced amounts, not too much, or little, can cure us.  Here, there is extreme accuracy, but, accuracy, itself, is about a delicate balance of things.

In general, it's much easier to quickly tear things down than to properly build them up with incremental or measured good acts.  Haven't IQ's risen markedly with the overall health of the population, in the last hundred years?  And, on the decline, again?  If I recall, it takes millions of years for a species' genetic material to normalize on its own.

In other words, a wrong can be very wrong in many ways, whereas a right is just right in just one way.  Although questions may be hard to answer, the answers, themselves, over long periods of time, remain reasoned out (in a balanced way).  There are infinitely many ways to solve a given problem, but, each way admits only one overall solution to it, in which one solution may be more direct, elegant, etc, than another, but, each is still a matter of a balanced perspective and set of skills.

Comment: Thanks, I have lots of sympathy for your appeal to an Aristotelian balance.  On the other hand,  when there is a still a question of perspective. We are something, not nothing:  that's a truth for which there is no reasonable middle ground.  Climate change is bad for us. From my perspective that's extremely true. Some who  label climate-change-deniers as extremists would also regard  people as  extremists if they asserted the bad effects of climate change too sronlgy.

Comment: Hi.  We are something not everything, either.  We "exist" outside of nothing/everything, yet, within it.  We are "balanced/imbalanced" in the sense that our thoughts thus coincidentally match up with events around us.  It's like we, and the other life forms are the only ones to "guess" the right answers.  As with the pursuit of a theory of everything, the final solution can only be "guessed" at.  It's beyond us, yet, we could comprehend such if thus given it.  Something not completely intentional.

Answer (score -1):

Extremism is a construct (I agree) that has become increasingly prominent since 1900 (thank you for that info).  If it does  fill a semantic niche, it's a very elastic one, since extremism is a tendentious description. The elasticity has two sources (1) The concept depends on the speaker's perspective (as also does the word terrorism).  (2) The suffix -ism sometimes implies an attribute that is characteristic, rather than definitive, of a category but only makes sense if the category's definition is accepted.  The Catholic creed defines catholicism relatively unambiguously.   Parkinsonism resembles Parkinson's disease, a category that can be defined objectively. Similar objective authority  seems to attach to words such as extremism, barbarism and vulgarism, but there is no objective definition for categories such as these.  It looks as though the rise in usage of the term extremism reflect the history of Anglo-American politics over the last 100 years.